# What data structure to use in maintaining k most frequently dialed numbers in a phone?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was asked this question in an interview, "How to maintain k most frequent dialed numbers in a phone ?". So what kind of data structure to use in this case ?

Comment: A dictionary with the phone number as key and the count of dials as value?

Comment: Well no, you'd want a sort on the count to get the topK. I like this question, maybe the OP could tell us how much progress he made, perhaps starting with the pros and cons of using the "standard" structures

Comment: True "k most frequently dialed" doesn't seem like it'd match user expectations or be very useful, and it'd require you to keep track of every number ever dialed on the phone. I'd expect more recent calls to be more important - in fact, k most *recently* dialed would likely be more useful than k most *frequently* dialed, and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

The tasks are:

- Keep track of the #times each number is dialed;
- Keep track of top counted k numbers.

---

So, you'll have to use Augmented DS. In your case, this will be HashSet and PriorityQueue (aka Heap) of size k with minimum dialed number at the top.

Since the number of times a number has been dialed can only increase, this makes our job a bit easier in the sense that you will never have to pull a number out of Heap because its count went down. Instead you will only add a number that has been dialed and then remove the top of Heap because top is the least dialed number.

The class `PhoneNumber` would contain:

- the phone number;
- the count of times it has been dialed; and,
- a boolean to tell whether it is in top-k number or not.

---

General steps would be:

Whenever a number is dialed:

- Add it to HashSet if it has never been dialed before with a count of dials = 1 and the boolean tracking its presence in the heap to true;
- If it is already present in the HashSet, increase its dial count by 1 making sure the hashing function independent of dialing counts (otherwise you will not be able to retrieve the number back from HashSet);
- If the number is in Heap already (which you can know by the boolean in PhoneNumber object), increase its count and *heapify()* the heap again;
- If the number is not in Heap, add the number to the heap and then remove the top, setting the trakcing boolean of the removed number to false. This will ensure that top-k dialed numbers only are present in the heap;
- Make sure you don't remove the numbers until the heap's size = k.

---

**Space complexity:** O(n) for the *n* numbers dialed until now, stored in HashSet and referenced in Heap.

**Time Complexity**: <strike>O(k*Log(k))</strike> O(k + Log(k)) for each dialing of number because you have to heapify at each new dial. Since the rearrangement of keys will be done for only 1 number in the worst case, you iterate over k numbers and then sometimes do a Log(k) work for exactly one number. O(1) would be the complexity for getting the k top dialed numbers as they are right there in your heap.

Comment: There is no need to fully rebuild the heap every time a key changes. In a binary heap, it only takes log(k) to readjust when a key changes.

Comment: @JimMischel: I was looking for a way to get that done in Log(k) kind of time but we don't exactly know where that number is present in the heap. So we will have to iterate over all the numbers in the worst case. However, since we will move the keys only for one number, we can tighten the bound to O(k + log(k)) to account for rearrangement for only one key instead of k keys.

Answer (score 1):

Priority Queue (which is an implementation of a MaxHeap)

Answer (score 0):

A max heap which is known as Priority Queue in many programming languages can be used where each entry will `<phone_number, count_of_dial>` pair. The max heap will be sorted according to the `count_of_dial`. Top `k` items are the answer.

Comment: And how efficient is that? How do you determine if a number that you just called is in the heap? How do you update the heap when an existing number is called?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a structure where I have the number and how many time it was dialed. Would put that in a B-Tree organizing it according to the number of times the numbers was dialed.

1. Add O(log(n)) [Balanced]
2. Add O(n)      [NOT balanced]
3. Search O(log(n))
4. Balance O(log(n))
5. Add(not balanced) + balance O(log(n))

IN THE WORS CASE: Searching + Adding + balancing it would be O(n). The avarage complexity of all operation in a B-Tree is still O(log(n).

A B-Tree grows by the root not by the leaves, so it'll guarantee that is balanced all the time, since you keep control of it when inserting by splitting down the nodes and moving values down.

In this specific case where I don't have to forget the number that were once dialed is even simpler.

The advantage of it is that it'll be always ordered, so what you are looking for would be the 50 first "nodes(key/value)" of the tree.

Comment: How would you update it? When a new call is made, you have to find the number in your data structure, increase its count, and then modify its position in the tree. You probably should include the complexity of that operation, too.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this question is twofold:

1. To get you to ask questions.
2. To get you to talk through drawbacks and advantages of different approaches.

The interviewer isn't terribly interested in you getting the "right" answer, as much as he's interested in how you approach the problem. For example, the problem as stated is not well specified. You probably should have asked questions like:

- Most frequent over what period? All time? Per month? Year to date?
- How will this information be used?
- How frequently will the information be queried?
- How fast does response have to be?
- How many phone numbers do you expect it to handle?
- Is `k` constant? Or will users ask at one point for the top 10, and some other time for the top 100?

All of these questions are relevant to solving the problem.

Once you know all of the requirements, then you can start thinking about how to implement a solution. It could be as simple as maintaining a call count with every phone entry. Then, when the data is queried, you run a simple heap selection algorithm on the entire phone list, picking the top k items. That's a perfectly reasonable solution if queries are infrequent. The typical phone isn't going to have a huge number of called numbers, so this could work quite well.

Another possible solution would be to maintain the call count for each number, and then, after every call, run the heap selection algorithm and cache the result. The idea here is that the data can only update when a new call is made, and calls are *very* infrequent, in terms of computer time. If you could make a call every 15 seconds (quite unlikely), that's only 5,760 calls in a day. Even the slowest phone should be able to keep up with that.

There are other solutions, all of which have their advantages and disadvantages. Balancing memory use, CPU resources, simplicity, development time, and many other factors is a large part of what we do as software developers. The interviewer purposely under-specified a problem with a seemingly straightforward solution in order to see how you approach things.

If you did not do well on the interview, learn from it. Also understand that the interviewer probably thought you were technically competent, otherwise he wouldn't have moved on to see how well you approach problems. You're *expected* to ask questions. After all, anybody can regurgitate simple solutions to simple problems. But in the real world we don't get simple problems, and the people asking us to do things don't always fully specify the requirements. So we have to learn how to extract the requirements from them: usually by asking questions.